# ORACLE DELETE with converted columns

Tags: oracle, sql-delete

I'm transferring data from Oracle.
There is table named A and when there are overlapping columns in the process of moving them to table C, I am trying to delete them and put them in.
However, if A and C have the same column configuration, it works smoothly, but the column configuration is different, so I don't know what to do if I convert it.

What I've tried so far is as follows.

```
CREATE TABLE test.test_pk_a
(
  col_one   VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL,
  col_two   VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,
  col_three VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT test_pk_a_pk PRIMARY KEY(col_one,col_two)
);

INSERT INTO test_pk_a VALUES('A',1,1);
INSERT INTO test_pk_a VALUES('A',2,1);
INSERT INTO test_pk_a VALUES('A',3,1);


CREATE TABLE test.test_pk_c
(
  col_one_v   VARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL,
  col_two_v   VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,
  col_three_v VARCHAR2(8) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT test_pk_c_pk PRIMARY KEY(col_one_v,col_two_v)
);

INSERT INTO test_pk_c VALUES(10,'c',1);
INSERT INTO test_pk_c VALUES(20,'a',1);


DELETE 
  FROM (SELECT * 
          FROM test.test_pk_a A, test.test_pk_c C
         WHERE A.col_two*10 = C.col_one_v 
           AND LOWER(A.col_one)= C.col_two_v);
```

How should I modify this Query in order to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've meant to delete from the table **A**, then you can precede the subquery with `EXISTS` such as

```
DELETE test_pk_a
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 0
                 FROM test_pk_a A
                 JOIN test_pk_c C
                   ON A.col_two * 10 = C.col_one_v
                  AND LOWER(A.col_one) = C.col_two_v);
```

if you meant the common column names by *configuration* wouldn't be the case(no problem whether to have the same column names or not)

Comment: I meant to delete from table C, but your answer is helpful! My final query is like this. `DELETE FROM TEST_PK_C C
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM test_pk_a A WHERE A.col_two * 10 = C.col_one_v AND LOWER(A.col_one) = C.col_two_v); `